# How can I show a hidden list item on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display my parent `ul` on pageload. But my code is not working:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  ('ul:first').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul style="display:none">
  <li>I am visible</li>
  <ul style="display:none">
    <li>I am not visible</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is unclear. "code is not working" are ambiguous words. Please explain how this did not work. Runtime error, compiler error, etc. Till you post the necessary details, we cannot help you. Please post complete questions, with complete details.

Comment: I made a visual example, so you illustrate exactly what is not working. Just click on "Run code snippet"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You are missing `$` while selecting `element`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul:first').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul style="display:none">
  <li>I am visible</li>
  <ul style="display:none">
    <li>I am not visible</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```